# Word - have tabs in titles, but don't display those tabs in the table of contents

Tags: microsoft-word, tabs, table-of-contents

I have a document where I use the Word styles feature to style the document and also create a table of contents.

Now I have a situation where my titles contain a tab. Think of things like:
[image: Example]

So this is: [paragraph number] [tab] [title]

Now this gives me the following situation in the table of contents:

[image]

As you can see, it displays the tab here too. I would prefer it if the 'tab' would be replaced with two or three spaces *or* if the tab spacing could be changed. I already tried changing the tab stops of the second level in the contents, but that only messed things up (the dots disappeared and the page number appeared on the left side).

It would be great if it is possible to change the tab stops (for the second level) in the table of contents.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you could approach this. Personally I do not really like any of them. IMO it's not so hard to live with the first, but I suspect the other two will create more problems than they are worth.

The level 2 headings are styled with the TOC2 paragraph style (at least, in the English language version of Word), so you can change both the left indent and set the first tab in that style. You have to make sure that you do not insert a second tab position/type that would move the position and type of the page number. I wonder if that is what happened when you modified your tabs.

---

To remove the tabs altogether, you have to change the way the actual heading paragraphs are formatted. This is not a good approach IMO, because it means that you then have to add tabs manually at the beginning of each Heading's text, and the trouble with that is that Word then indents the paragraph. So it's awkward. (I usually insert a character first, then the tab, then delete the character to get around that.)

You can do that by, e.g. using the *Home->Paragraph->MultiLevel List* dropdown, selecting the MultiLevel list style you are using it and going into *Define New Multilevel List...* . In there, ensure you are seeing the whole dialog box (click the *More >>* button at the bottom left if you see it). Then level 1 and set the Follow Number With to "Space" or "Nothing". Then go through all your heading paragraphs and add those manual tabs. You should find that the other Heading styles are changed also but if not, you may be able to modify them in the dialog.

Now, when you regenerate the ToC, the lines should contain a single space regardless of whether you chose Space or Nothing, and regardless of whether or not you insert a Tab. But to get the correct Heading layout in the body of the document, you will need to add those tabs back in manually.

---

Finally, you can insert { TC } fields and build a non-default ToC using e.g. a { TOC \f \h \z } field. But that means that you have to insert/remove the TC fields to match your headings, and you either have to maintain the numbers and texts in the TC fields manually, or that you have to use cross-reference fields in the TC fields. In the latter case you still have to set the TC field's Level manually. That's not ideal because cross-reference fields rely on *bookmarks* marking the relevant texts, and as you modify heading text and position, it's easy to mess up what those bookmarks are covering. Using cross-referencing means that you have to put the TC field somewhere other than the Heading paragraph (perhaps in an empty paragraph above or blow, or you could put them all somewhere near the TOC field.

But for example, suppose you have a level 2 heading like this

1.1  Geschiedenis

then click outside the heading and use References->Captions->Cross-reference. Uncheck the "Insert as Hyperlink" option. Insert two references, one to the Paragraph Number of the heading, and the other to the Paragraph Text.

Use ctrl-F9 to insert a pair of field code braces `{  }` and type the following between them `TC " " \l 2` (since it's a level 2 heading) so you have

```
{ TC " " \l 2 }
```

Now cut/paste those two references into the TC field - you should end up with a set of nested fields that look something like this:

```
{ TC "{ REF _Ref44430901 \r } { REF _Ref44429279" }" \l 2 }
```

TC fields are automatically formatted as hidden text, but you need to ensure that the two REF fields are not formatted as Hidden. That's why it's easier not to create them while the insertion point is inside the TC field.

Select and update those TC fields, then select and update the ToC field. You may need to modify the ToC options to give you the dotted tabs.

Comment: Hi @yokki, thanks for the extensive answer. I’ll check it this afternoon and let you know. Inserting {TC} fields is a bit too much of a hassle for now (it’s also a shared document, so everybody would need to know how it works). I’ll let you know. Cheers, Ralph

Comment: Hello @yokki, thanks for the suggestion to change the tab stops. That worked nicely. I use a Dutch version of Word and there the paragraph style was called 'Inhopg 2' (inhoudsopgave = table of contents). To be honest, I didn't try the solution of creating references, because the first solution worked and I didn't want to risk the file being messed up. Thanks, Ralph

Answer (score 0):

You can try moving the Left tab stop to be closer to the numbers. Put the cursor at the beginning of title. Go to the rule, click on the left tab stop and move it left. After that, if you update the table of contents, it won't change.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Hi @ReddyLutonadio thanks for the answer. It would be great if such a simple thing would prove to be the solution. I’ll check it out this afternoon and let you know. Cheers, Ralph

Comment: Hello @ReddyLutonadio I just tried it, but unfortunately it doesn't work.. Changing the tab-stops works fine, but when I update the table of contents is does with me. I'm using Word for Mac, so that's probably causing the problem, although it would seem weird to me that Microsoft would let those two versions behave differently... I thank you for your answer and your time! Best, Ralph